# Add moderator-visible review task links to posts that are enqueued

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, moderator-tools

Over the past few months, I've found that I regularly need the ability to look up review tasks associated with posts, for things like diagnosing odd voting patterns, verifying that the queues are operating as expected, or tracking down rejected suggested edits.

Currently, doing this is... Somewhat tedious. More importantly though, *moderators* can't do it at all!

I'm not entirely sure this would *need* to be moderator-only, but I've had requests from moderators for this information and can see where it would be helpful to them on occasion (for the same reasons it's been helpful to me), whereas it might well just be noise for most other folks.

Therefore, I propose an option be added to each posts's moderator menu that will provide a list of any and all review tasks associated with it. A spiritual brother to the current "Show flag history" option:

[image: A sequential history of review tasks created for this item]

Comment: Oh, HELLS YEAH.

Comment: Yes yes, thank you. Finally find out who up voted that spam post.

Comment: This would be particularly useful for rejected edits, because we often get flags for attempts at vandalism or spam and it's incredibly difficult to track back rejections right now.

Comment: @ʞɔɥls: well, you still won't be able to see *votes* - but it'll clearly show situations where, say, a single post got reviewed in the same queue four times, which will hopefully be less common now but has been rather problematic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh, hey! Look what Emmett did:

[image: It's the review history. What did you expect?]